# Decoded automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

So I have this list on special character `~, #, %, &, *, {, }, , :, ;, /, [, ], <, >, ?, |, ' and "` and the double quotation mark was throwing an unterminated string error. So I looked at how I am getting the characters.

```
  $("#files").multiupload({
      ....
      invalidFileNameCharacter: "<%= MyObj.GetInvalidFileNameCharacters%>",
   });
```

So I decided to encode it; changing the code to this

```
   $("#files").multiupload({
      .....
      invalidFileNameCharacter: "<%= Server.HtmlEncode(MyObj.GetInvalidFileNameCharacters)%>",
    });
```

The value is then captured and used here

```
warnSelector.html("<div><span>" + InvalidFileNameCharacters+ "</span></div>");
```

What was surprising was that when it rendered in the page the characters where correctly decoded `~, #, %, &, *, {, }, , :, ;, /, [, ], <, >, ?, |, '` becuase I was expecting this `~, #, %, &amp;, *, {, }, , :, ;, /, [, ], &lt;, &gt;, ?, |, &#39; and &quot` Does anyone know why it was decoded? I have traced the code and there isn't explicit decoding. Could it be the `html()` is implicitly decoding it?

Comment: It is not decoding. After encoding they just turned into html entities and browser is treating them accordingly. For example, &lt; is a html entity for '<', browser shows '<'.

Comment: try using `text()` instead of `html()`